# How to use generics in Unmarshal (go 1.18)

Tags: go, generics, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm new to golang generics and have the following setup.

1. I've gathered loads of different kinds of reports.
2. Each report has enclosing fields
3. So I wrapped it in a `ReportContainerImpl`

I've used a type argument of  `[T Reportable]` where the `Reportable` is defined as follows

```golang
type Reportable interface {
    ExportDataPointReport | ImportDataPointReport | MissingDataPointReport | SensorThresoldReport
}
```

Each of the type in the *type constraint* is structs that is to be embedded in the container.

```golang
type ReportContainerImpl[T Reportable] struct {
    LocationID string `json:"lid"`
    Provider string `json:"pn"`
    ReportType ReportType `json:"m"`
    Body T `json:"body"`
}
```

I use a discriminator `ReportType` to determine the concrete type when `Unmarshal`.

```golang
type ReportType string

const (
    ReportTypeExportDataPointReport ReportType = "ExportDataPointReport"
    ReportTypeImportDataPointReport ReportType = "ImportDataPointReport"
    ReportTypeMissingDataPointReport ReportType = "MissingDataPointReport"
    ReportTypeSensorThresoldReport ReportType = "SensorThresoldReport"
)
```

Since *go* does not support type assertion for *struct* (only *interfaces*) it is not possible to cast the type when `Unmarshal`. Also *go* does not support pointer to the *"raw"* generic type. Hence, I've created a *interface* that the `ReportContainerImpl` implements.

```golang
type ReportContainer interface {
    GetLocationID() string
    GetProvider() string
    GetReportType() ReportType
    GetBody() interface{}
}
```

The problem I then get is that I cannot do type constrains on the return type in any form or shape and am back at *"freetext semantics"* on the `GetBody()` function to allow for type assertion when `Unmarshal` is done.

```golang
    container, err := UnmarshalReportContainer(data)

    if rep, ok := container.GetBody().(ExportDataPointReport); ok {
      // Use the ReportContainerImpl[ExportDataPointReport] here...
    }
```

Maybe I'm getting this wrong? - but however I do this, I always end up with somewhere needs a `interface{}` or to know the *exact* type before `Unmarshal`

- Do you have a better suggestion how to solve this in a type (safer) way?

Cheers,
Mario :)

For completeness I add the `UnmarshalReportContainer` here

```golang
func UnmarshalReportContainer(data []byte) (ReportContainer, error) {

    type Temp struct {
        LocationID string `json:"lid"`
        Provider string `json:"pn"`
        ReportType ReportType `json:"m"`
        Body *json.RawMessage `json:"body"`
    }

    var temp Temp
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &temp)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    switch temp.ReportType {
    case ReportTypeExportDataPointReport:
        var report ExportDataPointReport
        err := json.Unmarshal(*temp.Body, &report)
        return &ReportContainerImpl[ExportDataPointReport]{
            LocationID: temp.LocationID,
            Provider:   temp.Provider,
            ReportType: temp.ReportType,
            Body:       report,
        }, err

      // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a mis-application of generics. Generics do not replace the use of interfaces: [When To Use Generics](https://go.dev/blog/when-generics) may have some useful guidance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> but however I do this, I always end up with somewhere needs a interface{} or to know the exact type before Unmarshal

Precisely.

The concrete types needed to instantiate some generic type or function like `ReportContainerImpl` or `UnmarshalReportContainer` must be known at compile time, when you write the code. JSON unmarshalling instead occurs at run-time, when you have the byte slice populated with the actual data.

To unmarshal dynamic JSON based on some discriminatory value, you still need a `switch`.

> Do you have a better suggestion how to solve this in a type (safer) way?

Just forgo parametric polymorphism. It's not a good fit here. Keep the code you have now with `json.RawMessage`, unmarshal the dynamic data conditionally in the `switch` and return the concrete structs that implement `ReportContainer` interface.

---

As a general solution — if, and only if, you can overcome this chicken-and-egg problem and make type parameters known at compile time, you can write a minimal generic unmarshal function like this:

```
func unmarshalAny[T any](bytes []byte) (*T, error) {
    out := new(T)
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, out); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return out, nil
}
```

This is only meant to illustrate the principle. Note that `json.Unmarshal` already accepts any type, so if your generic function actually does nothing except `new(T)` and return, like in my example, it is no different than "inlining" the entire thing as if `unmarshalAny` didn't exist.

```
v, err := unmarshalAny[SomeType](src)
```

functionally equivalent as

```
out := &SomeType{}
err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, out)
```

If you plan to put more logic in `unmarshalAny`, its usage may be warranted. Your mileage may vary; in general, don't use type parameters when it's not actually necessary.